# Rearming a jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function like so:

```
$('.edit_qty_button').click(function() {

    var qty = $(this).parent();
    qty.html('<input class="qty_input_box" type="text" /><br><span class="done_editing_button">Done</span>');

    $('.done_editing_button').click(function() {

        qty.html('99<br><span class="edit_qty_button">Edit</span>');

    });

});
```

The issue I have is that once, the done editing button is pushed, it is not possible to click edit qty button to edit again.  Somebody explained to me how to fix this once but I cannot remember at all, please advise!

Comment: Use the `.on` event for jQuery instead of binding it immediately.

Comment: it's because you don't add the event listener to the button when you re-add it to the html. best would be to hide the button instead of removing it from the html.

Comment: use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: You should use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change your selector to this it will work. This feature is called event delegation

```
$(document).on("click", '.edit_qty_button', function() { 
    ..
}
```

See the documentation about the `on` function here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

edit: The link from  @Arun P Johny and @Satpal are also very useful! (see comments above)
http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

edit:
`$(document).on("click"` // This part will bind a click event on the document

`'.edit_qty_button'` // This is the filter (filter on class name), click events will bubble up to the document which filters it. When it is valid it will execute the function

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to make sense of it but I'm having trouble getting it.

Comment: Edit: sorry, modified my posts, there was an error with it + will update my post with some explanation :)

Comment: Thanks, that works. I figured event delegation, will now go read up on on(). Thank you!